# Building string with float variables

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-formatting

How can i build a `NSString` variable consisting of `string` and `float` variables?

I assume i need to cast the floats to strings, but i cant see how this is done without creating alot of messy and ugly code.

I want to build something like this: `String`+ `Float`+ `String`+ `Float`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strings are very different in Objective C from their Java counterparts. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how Objective C works. In Java, you would use:

```
String yourString = string1 + " " + float1 + " " + string2 + " " + float2;
```

You cannot do the same in Objective C. To do something to the same effect, you would need:

```
NSString* yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %f %@ %f", string1, float1, string2, float2];
```

This would result in the equivalent to the Java statement. `%@` indicates you want to format an object into the string, and `%f` indicates a floating point value.

When formatting floats in an NSString, you can specify how many decimal places you want to truncate to by placing a value in between the `%` and `f`. For example, to round the first float to 2 decimal places and the second one to 5 decimal places:

```
NSString* yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2f %@ %.5f", string1, float1, string2, float2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text %f some more text %f", floatVar, anotherFloat];
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked:

Assume:

```
NSString *str1 = @"string one";
NSString *str2 = @"string two";

float f1 = 1.0;
float f2 = 2.0;

NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %f. %@: %f.", str1, f1, str2, f2];
NSLog(@"%@", answer); // This will print "string one: 1.000000. string two: 2.000000."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float sampleFloatVariable = 50.0;

NSString *floatintoText = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%f",sampleFloatVariable];

NSLog(@" float text %@",floatintoText);
```

Comment: string + float ..didnt understood it.. can you give an example ..what you want to achieve